# Owl carousel is not working on bootstrap tabs nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, owl-carousel-2

I am new on jquery.
I wanted to slide my nav item using `owl carousel`. But its not working.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav nav nav-pills bottom owl-carousel"  id="owler"  role="tablist">
    <div role="tab" class="tab-red   active  item expert-item">
       <a href="#red-tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    red
       </a>
    </div>
    <div role="tab" class="tab-orange   item expert-item">
       <a href="#orange-tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
          orange
       </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $("#owler").owlCarousel({
   responsiveClass:true,
   center: true,
   loop:true,
   autoplay:false,
   nav: false,
   navText: [
    '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
    '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
   ]
});
```

[Live links](https://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/qYGpVb)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some more nav item, it will work.

Comment: Concise twin brother of an earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504866/owl-carousel-is-not-working-on-bootstrap-tabs-nav/50505468?noredirect=1#answer-50505468.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works, but you just need to add some more tabs to the navigation links.
Take a look at [this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxerYL) for reference.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav nav-tabs user-tabs bottom owl-carousel"  id="owler"  role="tablist">
    <div role="presentation" class="tab-red   active  item expert-item">
        <a href="#red-tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        name
    </a>
    </div>
  <div role="presentation" class="tab-red   active  item expert-item">
        <a href="#red-tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        name
    </a>
    </div>
  <div role="presentation" class="tab-red   active  item expert-item">
        <a href="#red-tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        name
    </a>
    </div>
  <div role="presentation" class="tab-red   active  item expert-item">
        <a href="#red-tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        name
    </a>
    </div>
  <div role="presentation" class="tab-red   active  item expert-item">
        <a href="#red-tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        name
    </a>
    </div>
  <div role="presentation" class="tab-orange   item expert-item">
        <a href="#orange-tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              roll
        </a>
    </div>
   <div role="presentation" class="tab-green    item expert-item">
        <a href="#green-tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
             subject
        </a>
    </div>
    <div role="presentation" class="tab-yellow    item expert-item">
        <a href="#yellow-tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            and what
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you don't have an additional navigation items, you might also want to shrink the tabs you have to fill the remaining space (for example, using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property on an element inside flexbox container).

Comment: did you see that on Bootstrap 4 its not working. [https://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/QrRxVb] (https://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/QrRxVb)

Comment: @SifulIslam, either we have a different understanding of the word "works", or it really works.
By writing "it works" I mean, that it is possible to drag owl carousel items left and right.
Can you, please, check once again?